# in codeigniter, i am using same name for multiple inputs(type="text"), during submit i want to allow at least one value, how can i validate?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

My code snippet:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Weight</label>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){ ?>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Weight" name="weight[]" id="weight_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control weight_cls" />
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="err"><?php echo form_error('weight[]'); ?></div>
</div>
```

If i use following CI validation:

```
$this -> form_validation -> set_rules('weight[]', 'Weight', 'required|numeric');
```

Then it will not allow until fill all fields..

I want to allow at least one.. how can i??

Comment: Don't use CodeIgniter form validation but write your own rule. Like `if (count($this->input->post('weight')) == 0) { // error }`

Comment: but there is need of codeigniter validation for other fields.. then how can i?

Comment: Put your rule after CodeIgniter form validation rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own validation method :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('weight[]', 'Weight', 'callback_weight_check');
```

And in the same controller :

```
public function weight_check($weight)
{
     if(count(array_filter($weight)) == 0) {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('weight_check', 'Fill at least one value');
         return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

More infos : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: one extra bracket with if statement.. otherwise working fine

Answer (score 1):

Get the input form form

```
$weight    = $this->input->post('weight'); //or get as your form
```

$weight is an array so you can use foreach loop to validate each element as below:

```
foreach($weight as $key=>$val) 
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("weight[".$key."]", "weight", 'required|numeric');
   // you can have one more row as per your requirement.  
}
```